# how to trigger FB.login event in javascript if FB.getLoginStatus is not connected

Tags: javascript, facebook

I am really in dilemma with Facebook Login problem.

Here is the original source.

```
FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
        if (response.status === 'connected') {
            item.access_token=response.authResponse.accessToken; 
            console.log('token facebook: '+item.access_token);
            if(!item.project.edit)
                sceduleTask(item);    
            else
                updateTask(item);    
        }else
        {                      
                FB.login(function(response){
                  item.access_token=response.authResponse.accessToken;                             
                  if(!item.project.edit)
                        sceduleTask(item);    
                  else
                        updateTask(item);                  

              });                     
        }
   });
```

The reason why I don't do FB.getLoginStatus on page loading is because I can't know when user click "Share with Facebook" button which invokes the above code.

So, I want to check FB login status by just the time when user click "Share with Facebook" button, and get login dialog only if user not logged in yet.

The current source makes popup block because of FB.login in callback blocked in browser.

I want to get elegant solution to solve this issue.

Help me!!!

Comment: There is no real “elegant” solution to this. You need to call FB.login _directly_ on a user interaction (like a click) for the popup blocker to let it through. Of course you could just call FB.login in any case, when the user clicks your share button (or whatever it is.) Users that have already logged in before will then only see the popup pop up and then close itself again.